# using relationship and inheritance in roomdatabase

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, android-sqlite, android-room, relationship

I'm trying to create a simple e-wallet app and I want to save the details of each change of the account balance along with the current balance right after any transaction. I want to save these information in roomdatabase but I have problems with handing the inheritance with room.
basically I have a superclass BalanceChanges:

```
`open class BalanceChanges(

 open var type:Int,

 open var referenceid:String,

 open val date:String)`
```

and several subclasses like this TopUp class for example:

```
`data class TopUp(

                 var amount:Int,

                 override val date: String, val bank:String,

                 val odersn:String,

                 override var referenceid:String,

                 override var type:Int = TYPE_TOPUP)

    :BalanceChanges(type,referenceid, date)`
```

what I want to save is something like this:

```
`class BalanceChangesWithCurrentBalance(

    val referenceid: String,

    val balanceChanges: BalanceChanges,

    val currentbalance: Int) {
}`
```

a class that have both current balance and one BalanceChanges which is the superclass represent multile subclass like that TopUp Class. So How do I get, insert that class to room

I did some research and think about using relationship and using that referenceid field which is shared and unique buy all the classes, but the really tricky part is how can I handle that superclass and it's
subclasses. Should U use multiple relationship to the tables that contain each subclasses or can I store all the subclasses in the one table.

Comment: What is the purpose of a class like TopUp if the additional properties it has are inaccessible because you upcast it to BalanceChanges before using it in BalanceChangesWithCurrentBalance?

Comment: BalanceChangesWithCurrentBalance is a class that i created to pass data to the recyclerview adapter buy a list of it. Basically just a class with any type of balance change like topup with an int value of balance. I can use all kind of blance changes inside the adapter through viewtype( BalanceChanges class has a companion oject for that but it's not related to room so i do not include it). I add the referenceid filed for trying to make a relationship with that balanceChanges value but i'm totally lost at solving how to make relationships to the subclasses from that superclass value.

Comment: No need to worry about that BalanceChangesWithCurrentBalance class. Any way to store those subclasses like topup with their corresponding current balances is OK

Answer (score 0):

Storing the balance with an entry is prone to complications e.g. say an entry is deleted or updated for some reason then all entries after the entry would have to be updated.

It would not be that hard to extract a running balance calculated when doing the extract.

Perhaps consider the following that demonstrates.

First some constants which can simplify matters such as the SQL for the Query:-

```
const val DATABASE_VERSION: Int = 1
const val DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db"
const val ENTRY_TABLE_NAME = "entry"
const val ENTRY_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN_NAME = "${ENTRY_TABLE_NAME}timestamp"
const val ENTRY_AMOUNT_COLUMN_NAME = "${ENTRY_TABLE_NAME}amount"
const val ENTRY_DESCRIPTION_COLUMN_NAME = "${ENTRY_TABLE_NAME}description"
```

The demo just uses a single table for the entries (not sure what/why you want sub-classes):-

```
@Entity(tableName = ENTRY_TABLE_NAME)
class Entry(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = ENTRY_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN_NAME)
    var entryTimestamp: Long=System.currentTimeMillis(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = ENTRY_AMOUNT_COLUMN_NAME)
    var entryAmount: Double,
    @ColumnInfo(name = ENTRY_DESCRIPTION_COLUMN_NAME)
    var entryDescription: String
)
```

For retrieving the entries with a running balance the following POJO:-

```
data class TransactionsWithBalance(
    @Embedded
    val entries: Entry,
    val balance: Double
)
```

The most complicated bit the `@Dao` annotated interface that caters for insertion and the all important extract with the running balance:-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insertEntry(transaction: Entry): Long

    @Query(" SELECT " +
            "*" + /*<<<<< ALL columns from the table */
            /* an additional derived column named balance that:- */
            /* SELECTS the sum of the entryAmount From the entry table that have a lower or the same timestamp */
            /* after the constants are resolved the SQL generated for the sub query is :- */
            /*     (SELECT sum(entryamount) FROM `entry` WHERE entrytimestamp <= t.entrytimestamp) */
            /* Note that to differentiate between what is the same table used twice the AS t for the first use */
            ", (SELECT sum(${ENTRY_AMOUNT_COLUMN_NAME}) FROM `${ENTRY_TABLE_NAME}` WHERE ${ENTRY_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN_NAME} <= t.${ENTRY_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN_NAME}) AS balance " +
            "FROM ${ENTRY_TABLE_NAME} AS t ORDER BY ${ENTRY_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN_NAME}")
    fun getEntriesWithBalance(): List<TransactionsWithBalance>
}
```

To allow the above to be demonstrated an `@Database` annotated abstract class that ties all of the above together and allows the database to be created/accessed:-

```
@Database(entities = [Entry::class], exportSchema = false, version = DATABASE_VERSION)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAO(): AllDAO
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity of demo */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

Last some Activity code to demonstrate use of the above to insert some data and to then extract the data with a running balance:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAO
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAO()

        var insertCount = 0
        var attemptCount = 0
        for (i in 1..100 step 5) {
            attemptCount++
            if (dao.insertEntry(Entry(entryAmount = (i.toDouble() + (i.toDouble() / 10.00)), entryDescription = "i.")) > 0) insertCount++
        }
        Log.d("DBINFO","Inserted ${insertCount} rows, ${attemptCount} attempted")
        for (e in dao.getEntriesWithBalance()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Entry made on ${e.entries.entryTimestamp} for $${e.entries.entryAmount} desc being ${e.entries.entryDescription}. BALANCE ${e.balance}")
        }
    }
}
```

So 20 rows will be inserted (assuming that each insert takes more than 1 millisec), each with an increasing amount based the value of the iterator which increases by 5 so is 1, then 6 ...., that is the value is the value of the iterator plus 1/10th of the iterator just so that Double's are definitely used.

- not that Doubles should really be used for financial stuff, but that's another topic.

When the above is run (for the first time), then the log includes:-

```
2023-08-11 19:04:17.019 D/DBINFO: Inserted 20 rows, 20 attempted


2023-08-11 19:04:17.027 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656909 for $1.1 desc being i.. BALANCE 1.1
2023-08-11 19:04:17.028 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656953 for $6.6 desc being i.. BALANCE 7.699999999999999
2023-08-11 19:04:17.028 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656955 for $12.1 desc being i.. BALANCE 19.799999999999997
2023-08-11 19:04:17.028 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656972 for $17.6 desc being i.. BALANCE 37.4
2023-08-11 19:04:17.028 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656974 for $23.1 desc being i.. BALANCE 60.5
2023-08-11 19:04:17.028 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656976 for $28.6 desc being i.. BALANCE 89.1
2023-08-11 19:04:17.028 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656978 for $34.1 desc being i.. BALANCE 123.19999999999999
2023-08-11 19:04:17.028 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656980 for $39.6 desc being i.. BALANCE 162.79999999999998
2023-08-11 19:04:17.028 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656983 for $45.1 desc being i.. BALANCE 207.89999999999998
2023-08-11 19:04:17.028 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656986 for $50.6 desc being i.. BALANCE 258.5
2023-08-11 19:04:17.028 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656989 for $56.1 desc being i.. BALANCE 314.6
2023-08-11 19:04:17.028 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656992 for $61.6 desc being i.. BALANCE 376.20000000000005
2023-08-11 19:04:17.028 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656994 for $67.1 desc being i.. BALANCE 443.30000000000007
2023-08-11 19:04:17.028 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656996 for $72.6 desc being i.. BALANCE 515.9000000000001
2023-08-11 19:04:17.028 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744656999 for $78.1 desc being i.. BALANCE 594.0000000000001
2023-08-11 19:04:17.029 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744657000 for $83.6 desc being i.. BALANCE 677.6000000000001
2023-08-11 19:04:17.029 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744657006 for $89.1 desc being i.. BALANCE 766.7000000000002
2023-08-11 19:04:17.029 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744657009 for $94.6 desc being i.. BALANCE 861.3000000000002
2023-08-11 19:04:17.029 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744657011 for $100.1 desc being i.. BALANCE 961.4000000000002
2023-08-11 19:04:17.029 D/DBINFO: Entry made on 1691744657014 for $105.6 desc being i.. BALANCE 1067.0000000000002
```

So as can be seen the balance is calculated according to the data that exists and will change if any of the data is deleted or updated when extracted.

- note the rounding issues aka storing as Double/decimal results in inexact/approximate values

The database itself, via App Inspection, has the entry table as:-

[image]